# ValueError: Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'histnorm' property of histogram

Tags: python, machine-learning, histogram

I am getting this error -

> ValueError: 
>       Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'histnorm' property of histogram
>           Received value: 'count'

when I try to run this code -

```
def plotHist(df,nameOfFeature):
    cls_train = df[nameOfFeature]
    data_array = cls_train
    hist_data = np.histogram(data_array)
    binsize = .5

    trace1 = go.Histogram(
        x=data_array,
        histnorm='count',
        name='Histogram of Wind Speed',
        autobinx=False,
        xbins=dict(
            start=df[nameOfFeature].min()-1,
            end=df[nameOfFeature].max()+1,
            size=binsize
        )
    )

    trace_data = [trace1]
    layout = go.Layout(
        bargroupgap=0.3,
         title='The distribution of ' + nameOfFeature,
        xaxis=dict(
            title=nameOfFeature,
            titlefont=dict(
                family='Courier New, monospace',
                size=18,
                color='#7f7f7f'
            )
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            title='Number of labels',
            titlefont=dict(
                family='Courier New, monospace',
                size=18,
                color='#7f7f7f'
            )
        )
    )
    fig = go.Figure(data=trace_data, layout=layout)
    py.iplot(fig)

plotHist(df,'Pregnancies')
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @Carcigenicate What is meant by stack trace of the error?

Comment: There should have been part of the error that tells you where exactly the error took place. What you posted here is only part of the error.